# Using TypeScript within a WordPress child theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, typescript

I'm currently having a `js` folder in my WordPress child theme:

> my-child/js/*.js

In my JS files, I'm using jQuery. For a better code quality, I'm thinking about changing the `.js` files into `.ts` files and include a compiler.

Is this a wise idea? I'm currently not sure if this is possible within WordPress and PHP because I need a `pom.xml` I think and a `tsconfig.json`.

Is there anyone who did this before and can guide me?

Comment: It seems debatable that "For a better code quality" is a sufficient reason (or a reason at all) to change everything in your WordPress theme. But if you really want it, you're not obliged to include `.ts` files and a compiler, you can keep them separated and only include already compiled `.js` files. Anyway, lots of scripts added to the page by plugins or such, or WordPress itself probably won't be convertible in TypeScript at all.

Comment: @Kaddath I only mean my custom JS files I've wrote. Not the default WordPress JS files. Only the files created in my JS folder in my child theme.